# Detect a permutation of sequence

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic, permutation

I have a list of numbers like this (array)

```
1 2 3 4
```

So my goal is the check given another array if this array if a permutation of the original example, the array `(3 4 1 2)` and `(1 2 4 3)` are permutations of the original but `(1 2 1 1)` or `(1 5 4 3)` not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two possible solutions are:

**(1)** `O(n)` space & average time solution will be to create a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), based on a hash table, of the data - and check if the histograms are identicals. The idea is - count how many each element appears in each list, and then check to see each element appears *exactly* the same times in each array.

pseudo code:

```
map1 = new map //first histogram
map2 = new map //second histogram
for each element in arr1: //create first histogram
   if (element in map1):
         map1.put(element,map1.get(element)+1)
   else:
         map1.put(element,1)
for each element in arr2: //create second histogram
   if (element in map2):
         map2.put(element,map2.get(element)+1)
   else:
         map2.put(element,1)
for each key in map 1: //check all elements in arr1 appear in arr2
   if map1.get(key) != map2.get(key):
        return false
//make sure the sizes also match, it means that each element in arr2 appears in arr1.
return arr1.length == arr2.length
```

**(2)** `O(nlogn)` time solution will be to sort both arrays, and then iterate and check if they are identical.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit the first alternative ?

Comment: @eli.rodriguez: The alternative is the histogram based solution? I added a pseudo code

Comment: Your histogram pseudocode implemented in Python: `from collections import Counter; return Counter(arr1) == Counter(arr2)`. :)

Comment: @Dougal: thanks. Since it was not python specific question - I thought it is good to show the OP how it actually goes (The python code will be translated to something very similar to this when interpeted I believe). But yes- it shows us the simplicity of high level language over the low level ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely have a sequence you may check if a given array is its permutation much faster.
Just calculate a sum of all element of your sequence and compare it with a sum of elements in the given array.

```
bool is_permutation(vector<int> &v, vector<int> &s) {
    // size of the sequence
    int v_size = v.size();
    // size of probable permutation.
    int s_size = s.size();
    // Calculate a sum of all elements of the sequence
    int sum_of_sequence = (v_size * (1 + v_size)) / 2;
    // Count actual sum of elements
    int sum_of_all_elements = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    // If the sums are equal the array contains a permuted sequence
    return sum_of_sequence == sum_of_all_elements;
}
```

Comment: But can't sequences of the same length that are **not** permutations of each other yield the same sum? Eg. `5 7 9 11` and `0 1 2 29`. What you need to do is check 2 things:

  0) both sequences are the same length,
  1) each element of sequence `A` appears exactly once in sequence `B` (or viceversa)